# How to run foreground service with open Camera from another foreground service in Android 11?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions, android-11

I am testing now open camera in `foreground service` in Android 11 and I have problem with new Android 11 restrictions: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Pseudo code:

```
//Service1 is started by JobScheduler.
class Service1 extends Service {
    ...
    startForeground(ID_OF_SERVICE1_NOTIFICATION, getService1Notification())
    ...
    //Run another foreground service with open camera
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service2.class)
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, i)
    ...
}

class Service2 extends Service {
    ...
    startForeground(ID_OF_SERVICE2_NOTIFICATION, getService2Notification(), ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MANIFEST);
    openCamera() // <-- Policy exception
    ...
}
```

Class Service1 is started by `JobScheduler` with `startForeground()` and show notification to user. Service1 can start (`ContextCompat.startForegroundService()`) Service2 with `startForeground()` and show notification to user too. Service2 opens camera. The user sees notification all the time.

manifest edited:

```
<service android:name=".service.Service2"
    android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone"
    android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

Edited `starForeground()` in `Service2` with flag `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MANIFEST`: (a special value indicates to use all types set in manifest file)

The result from `Logcat`:

> Foreground service started from background can not have location/camera/microphone access: service com.example.test/.service.Service2

Tried also `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA|FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE`.

I would like to keep the automation in starting the camera for user.
Is there any way?

Comment: Do you *really* need *two* services? "Is there any way?" -- instead of `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MANIFEST`, have you tried using `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA|FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE`?

Comment: Yes. First service check user-defined conditions and second service is launched only if conditions are met. Behaviour of `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA|FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE` is the same as `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MANIFEST`. I tried it.

Comment: "First service check user-defined conditions and second service is launched only if conditions are met" -- FWIW, to me that seems like it could be one service, rather than two.

Comment: Will this help solve the problem in question? (There is a lot of other logic.) It's better to have it separated.

Comment: "Will this help solve the problem in question?" -- quite possibly. Your problem seems to stem from Service A trying to start Service B. If there *is* no Service B, perhaps your problem goes away.

Comment: I need to have Service A and Service B separated. Both services doing different things..
Service A is started by JobScheduler.

Comment: Using camera+mic. on background should be enabled (as permission) by the user.. Android does not give the user that option.. :-(

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, since android 11 there is no way to *automatically* start the camera from a foreground service, if the app was not visible to the user since the start of the app process. The user must **interact** with the application in order to be able to use the camera. According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services?hl=ca#while-in-use-restrictions), these are the ways for an app to be considered *interacted with*, without actually opening an activity:

> - The service is started by a system component.
> - The service is started by interacting with app widgets.
> - The service is started by interacting with a notification. [**note: Interacting! It is not enough to display the notification**]
> - The service is started as a PendingIntent that is sent from a different, visible app.
> - The service is started by an app that is a device policy controller that is running in device owner mode.
> - The service is started by an app which provides the VoiceInteractionService. The service is started by an app that has the START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND privileged permission.

Comment: `if the app was not visible to the user since the start of the app process` - and how to check it? Is there any new method on Android 11 to check if there was an user interaction? p.s. it's needed in my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67572259/widget-cant-start-a-service-on-device-boot-on-android-11-until-some-activity-is

Comment: There is a way through the `AppOpsManager` class. I answered your question in detail in the other thread. I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @BalazsBanyai could you please share the thread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67590163/2764357