# Widget can't start a service on device boot on Android 11 until some activity is launched

Tags: android, android-service, android-widget, foreground-service, android-11

```
val startServiceIntent = TestService.getServiceIntent(context).let {
    PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, it, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}
val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.layout_app_widget).apply {
    setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.start_service_btn, startServiceIntent) // doesn't work on boot device
    setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.start_activity_btn, startActivityIntent) // works fine
}
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
```

How to treat such behaviour? How can I at least show a message to a user that a service can't be started from widget until he launches the app (make it visible) or launch an activity instead during this device session?

Because now nothing happens when I press the button to start the service until I launch the app at least once

Is there any method on Android 11 to check if we can start foreground service, camera and so on from background / widget? How to find out that user has launched an activity of app at least once for the current session of the device?

Comment: Have you [tried `PendingIntent.getForegroundService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/PendingIntent#getforegroundservice)?

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, it works. And it's great that from widget we can start to use camera and mic on Android 11 in foreground service without launching app (activity) after device boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @CommonsWare comment I need to use `PendingIntent.getForegroundService()` instead of `PendingIntent.getService()`

Answer (score 1):

After diving into the source code of Android OS, I found the following way to check whether the camera is restricted:

```kotlin
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
internal fun AppOpsManager.isCameraAllowedForPackage(packageName: String): Boolean {
    val res = unsafeCheckOpNoThrow(
        AppOpsManager.OPSTR_CAMERA,
        android.os.Process.myUid(),
        packageName
    )
    return res == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will need it also.